# Django add users as active even though user.is_active is set to False

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am trying to add new users as inactive, so they won't be able to login before confirming their email, but django adds new user as active (as seen through admin account) even though user.is_active is set to false

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form_data = form.cleaned_data
        username = form_data.get('username')
        raw_password = form_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
        user.is_active = False
        if user.is_active == False:
        user.email_confirmed = False
```

Comment: Where is `user.save()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not saved user object after do is active false. so it's always active:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form_data = form.cleaned_data
        username = form_data.get('username')
        raw_password = form_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
        user.is_active = False
        user.email_confirmed = False
        user.save()
```